# “apt-get install” using local packages acting weird

Tags: apt, package-management

I have downloaded packages using:

```
apt-get install -d gcc
```

Then, what I did was to save the "deb" package and upload it to another machine so that I can install it manually without download.

```
apt-get --no-download install gcc
```

I did this because I did not want to manage dependency as I am automatically installing "gcc" on some servers. I am afraid that updating often will change behavior of my program and break dependencies.

This program was running fine for 1 week. Today, my program failed with no changes at all. I know why this happens becase I do the following before installing "gcc":

```
apt-get update
```

Somehow, "apt-get update" will cause Ubuntu to no longer recognize my downloaded package (and I have verified that my package is indeed in the right location).

My question is:

1) Is there a better way to manage dependency?

2) Does anyone have any thoughts on why this is the case?

3) Can you save and load a specific version of the package index files. From my understanding, it seems that the package index files are the main culprits.